# column join variable number of columns and rearrangement

Tags: kdb

I want to join the following 3 tables row-wise, but also while moving some columns.

```
 q)
newtab1:([]basecol1:10 20 30;basecol2:40 50 60;L1Col1:"a","b","c";L1Col2:"d","e","f";L1Col3:"g","h","i")
newtab2:([]basecol1:100 200 300;basecol2:400 500 600;L1Col1:"a","b","c";L1Col2:"d","e","f";L2Col1:"j","k","l";L2Col2:"m","n","o";L1Col3:"g","h","i";L2Col3:"p","q","r")
newtab3:([]basecol1:1 2 3;basecol2:4 5 6;L1Col1:"a","b","c";L1Col2:"d","e","f";L2Col1:"j","k","l";L2Col2:"m","n","o";L3Col1:"s","t","u";L3Col2:"v","w","x";L1Col3:"g","h","i";L2Col3:"p","q","r";L3Col3:"y","z","z")
q)newtab3

basecol1 basecol2 L1Col1 L1Col2 L2Col1 L2Col2 L3Col1 L3Col2 L1Col3 L2Col3 L3Col3
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1        4        a      d      j      m      s      v      g      p      y
2        5        b      e      k      n      t      w      h      q      z
3        6        c      f      l      o      u      x      i      r      z
```

That is, "Col3" for each "L" should be moved to the end

I want to fill all the columns that don't have data with zeroes. That is, I need to add 3 columns to table 1 (and move one column), and 6 columns to table 2 (and move 2 columns). The columns are always labeled with this same pattern.
I started by creating the column names like this:

```
LegColNames:("Col1";"Col2";"Col3")
L1LegColNames: "L1",/:legColNames
```

but this makes them a string, how do I get those to be column names?

FWIW, in the real implementation, this will be joining hundreds of tables, and I'll need to take the table with the maximum number of Ls, and add the appropriate numbers of columns of zeroes to each table to make it equal that maximum.
It can go up as high as L13.

Answer (score 1):

Always break these things down into steps:

```
q)t:uj/[(newtab1;newtab2;newtab3)]  / join all tables

q)t2:0^t / this would fill the number columns
q)t2:flip {$[10h=type x;"0"^x;x]} each flip t / fill character columns with zeros

q){c:cols x; (c iasc c like "*Col3") xcols x}t2 / pull our columns to the end

basecol1 basecol2 L1Col1 L1Col2 L2Col1 L2Col2 L3Col1 L3Col2 L1Col3 L2Col3 L3Col3
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
10       40       a      d      0      0      0      0      g      0      0
20       50       b      e      0      0      0      0      h      0      0
30       60       c      f      0      0      0      0      i      0      0
100      400      a      d      j      m      0      0      g      p      0
200      500      b      e      k      n      0      0      h      q      0
300      600      c      f      l      o      0      0      i      r      0
1        4        a      d      j      m      s      v      g      p      y
2        5        b      e      k      n      t      w      h      q      z
3        6        c      f      l      o      u      x      i      r      z
```

The last part is the only bit that will be more difficult for many more tables. You'll want to parse the ending number and then find the sorted indices of the columns.

- Ryan

Comment: the first step with uj/ is working great, but after that it doesn't work. Everything is left as blank or empty strings, not sure which, technically.
fwiw, the entire table is strings; all numbers were casted to strings earlier on in this process.
 `jT2:0^joinedTab / probably should do nothing?`
 `jT2:flip {$[10h=type x;"0"^x;x]} each flip joinedTab` / does nothing
 `joinedTab[til 100][``L2Vstamp][0]` returns "", the type of which is 10. In qStudio under "result", the ones with "" have a green dot next to them and the "numbers" have "ab"

Comment: If an answer doesn't jump out at you from that description, I can include my specific data set here or email it to you but its quite large so I was trying to avoid that

Answer (score 0):

I'm starting to think that your fields are not char type but string type (list of char list) since you pointed out that `""` is one of the value of the field. If that's the case, using suggestion from @Ryan then:

```
q)newtab1:([]basecol1:string 10 20 30;basecol2:string 40 50 60;L1Col1:string 3?`2;L1Col2:string 3?`2;L1Col3:string 3?`2)
q)newtab2:([]basecol1:string 100 200 300;basecol2:string 400 500 600;L1Col1:string 3?`2;L1Col2:string 3?`2;L2Col1:string 3?`2;L2Col2:string 3?`2;L1Col3:string 3?`2;L2Col3:string 3?`2)
q)newtab3:([]basecol1:string 1 2 3;basecol2:string 4 5 6;L1Col1:string 3?`2;L1Col2:string 3?`2;L2Col1:string 3?`2;L2Col2:string 3?`2;L3Col1:string 3?`2;L3Col2:string 3?`2;L1Col3:string 3?`2;L2Col3:string 3?`2;L3Col3:string 3?`2)
q)t:uj/[(newtab1;newtab2;newtab3)]

q)@[`t;cols t;{?[x like "";count[x]#enlist 1#"0";x]}]      / using vector condition

q){c:cols x; (c iasc c like "*Col3") xcols x}t
basecol1 basecol2 L1Col1 L1Col2 L2Col1 L2Col2 L3Col1 L3Col2 L1Col3 L2Col3 L3Col3
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
"10"     "40"     "do"   "ma"   ,"0"   ,"0"   ,"0"   ,"0"   "gm"   ,"0"   ,"0"
"20"     "50"     "nc"   "bo"   ,"0"   ,"0"   ,"0"   ,"0"   "kp"   ,"0"   ,"0"
"30"     "60"     "df"   "mn"   ,"0"   ,"0"   ,"0"   ,"0"   "ec"   ,"0"   ,"0"
"100"    "400"    "ll"   "fp"   "ml"   "ce"   ,"0"   ,"0"   "ch"   "ho"   ,"0"
"200"    "500"    "cn"   "ol"   "fm"   "ij"   ,"0"   ,"0"   "bo"   "of"   ,"0"
"300"    "600"    "pk"   "pf"   "ii"   "ap"   ,"0"   ,"0"   "ed"   "ii"   ,"0"
,"1"     ,"4"     "jo"   "dh"   "cm"   "om"   "oa"   "ak"   "ap"   "no"   "kj"
,"2"     ,"5"     "kg"   "mh"   "ll"   "jk"   "nn"   "og"   "nn"   "gc"   "ig"
,"3"     ,"6"     "nh"   "mg"   "ob"   "fl"   "mi"   "lf"   "am"   "jo"   "nf"
```

`0^` and `"0"^` won't work on empty string:

```
q)"0"^""
""
```

Comment: This gives me a 'type error in my data set
@[`t;cols t;{?[x like "";count[x]#enlist 1#"0";x]}]
Also just wondering, whats the difference between 1#"0" and "0"

Comment: `1#"0"` is just another hacky way to turn the atom to a singleton list as `#` always return list as result. If you do `type` on each case, you will see the difference. I think it will be helpful to show us your `meta t`.